# Is it good practice using two navigation (component architecture) in the same app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it good practice using two navigation (in two different activities) in the same app?
For example: one navigation for register and login and second navigation for navigation drawer?

Comment: yes it would be great if you use different navigation for each module

Comment: I think one per `Activity` is ok if you are using `Fragment`s inside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is completely okay with Navigation documentation. It's even recommended for multiple activities.

In fact, Architecture Components is pushing the "single Activity multiple Fragments" idea. BUT:

> Note: The Navigation Architecture Component is designed for apps that have one main activity with multiple fragment destinations. The main activity “hosts” the navigation graph. **In an app with multiple activity destinations, each additional activity hosts its own navigation graph.**

See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Identify-destinations